# Create user database via code first ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, code-first

I'm trying to use a MySQL database with asp.net MVC via a code first approach and I don't know how to create the tables, I thought it would create by itself.

I get the message : "Table 'XXX.aspnetusers' doesn't exist"

Do I need to run migrations or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: if you are usig asp.net identity then you should chnage its provider to mysql , it is sql server by default .

Comment: Thanks Arash, but it was already done. I found that I need to update-database through the nuget-package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little further by  using update-database. You must have change your connection string and your provider to correspond to your MySql

Example :

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password=;database=myDB" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Provider :

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
```

You should also put this on your dbContext :

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

Thanks